# unknown "NumberFormatting" Issue

Tags: java, string, exception, number-formatting

(In advance, sorry for the lengthy and somewhat niche post but I'm terribly stuck) Complete Java programming newbie here, and I've been following along with the "Java ALL-IN-ONE for Dummies" book, and I've hit a snag I can't seem to get past. For some reason, my code, as well as the code taken from the book's download website, throws a NumberFormatException. My code is as follows..

```
`package videoRead;

import java.io.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class reader 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NumberFormat cf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        BufferedReader in = getReader("Movie.txt");
        Movie movie = readMovie(in);
        while (movie != null)
        {
        String msg = Integer.toString(movie.year);
        msg += ": " + movie.title;
        msg += " (" + cf.format(movie.price) + ")";
        System.out.print(msg);
        movie = readMovie(in);
        }

    }
    private static BufferedReader getReader(String name)
    {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try
        {
            File file = new File(name);
            in = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:\\Users\\hunte\\Desktop\\Movie.txt") );
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.print(
                    "the file doesn't exist.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return in;
    }

    private static Movie readMovie(BufferedReader in)
    {
        String title;
        int year;
        double price;
        String line = "";
        String[] data;

        try
        {
            line = in.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print("I/O Error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (line == null)
                return null;
        else
        {
            data = line.split("\t");
            title = data[0];
            year = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
            price = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);
            return new Movie(title, year, price);
        }
    }

    private static class Movie 
    {
        public String title;
        public int year;
        public double price;
        public Movie(String title, int year, double price)
        {
        this.title = title;
        this.year = year;
        this.price = price;
        }
    }

}
```

with the error code being

```
`1946: It's a Wonderful Life ($14.95)1972: Young Frankenstein ($16.95)1973: Star Wars ($17.95)1987: The Princess Bride ($14.95)1989: Glory ($14.95)Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "14.95"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at videoRead/videoRead.reader.readMovie(reader.java:65)
        at videoRead/videoRead.reader.main(reader.java:20)`
```

My question is why is this happening, and how can I fix it? or how do I go about catching the exception that won't break the code?

(Also, if anyone could tell me why my code won't split lines, that would be awesome as well)

Thanks!!

Comment: It says that `"14.95"` cannot be parsed as an integer. Do you perhaps have a misplaced currency value where a year is expected? That would be in the file

Comment: This is because of $ symbol in double value

Comment: Something is wrong there. `1946: It's a Wonderful Life ($14.95)` split with `\t` would probably give `1946:`, `It's a Wonderful Life` and `($14.95)`, which goes to `title`, `year` and `price` respectively (assuming it is a tab character after the colon. I suspect that there is only one tab there, and there is no tab after the colon.

Comment: There are several problems with your code, as already has been pointed out: assuming your file can be split correctly, you'd try to parse the title (`data[1]`) as an int and that's bound to fail. Even if you'd use the correct `data[0]` you'd try to parse `1946:` which should fail as well because of the trailing `:`. Additionally you'd try to parse `($14.95)` as a double and due to `($...)` it would fail as well. Hence: _first extract the correct parts from your line data then try to parse those._

Comment: can post your txt file data?

Comment: Btw, tabs are a hard to deal with delimiter, especially if you're manually creating the file or trying to read it. They are hard to distinguish from ordinary spaces and text might even contain some. Better use a more suitable delimiter like `;` (or besser a besser suited format like csv with escaping, json or xml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to error message this is the format of string that you have in text file, so below code split the line based on space delimiter and filter the values by removing all extra characters

Note: This code works if each each record is a separate line with this format in text file

```
String s ="1946: It's a Wonderful Life ($14.95)";
String[] ar = s.split(" ");
System.out.println(ar[0].substring(0, ar[0].length()-1));
String str = String.join("," ,Arrays.copyOfRange(ar, 1, ar.length-2)).replaceAll(",", " ");
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(ar[ar.length-1].substring(2, ar[ar.length-1].length()-1));
```

Output:

```
1946
It's a Wonderful
14.95
```

Answer (score 0):

```
price = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);
```

Gives you an error because the price value  in your `Movie.txt` file contains a `$` symbol. Remove the `$` from the file or replace it in your code as show in the code below

```
String p = data[2].toString().replace("$","");
price = Double.parseDouble(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that actually occurs, comes from:

```
 year = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
```

Not:

```
 price = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);
```

As in:

> For input string: "14.95"
>
> at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

The error tells you: you try to parse 14.95 as **int** value. Integer values don't have a floating point.

So the problem is: you are trying to parse a floating point number as int.

The underlying root cause: your split is wrong, you are putting/parsing wrong split data.

How to fix that wrong parsing of your input data is explained in the nice answer from deadpool.